# Error when trying to shuffle an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, nsmutablearray, shuffle

I'm trying to shuffle an NSMutableArray so that its order will be mixed up every-time someone loads the view.

In my `-(void)viewDidLoad` I'm putting the following code (as suggested by other users):

```
NSMutableArray *shuffleTwo = [self.chosenTeamDict objectForKey:@"clubs"];

int random = arc4random() % [shuffleTwo count]; 
for (int i = 0; i < [shuffleTwo count]; i++) {
    [shuffleTwo exchangeObjectAtIndex:random withObjectAtIndex:i]; 
}

NSLog(@"%@", shuffleTwo);
```

But when I do this and try and run the page, I get the following error:

```
2012-07-09 18:42:16.126 Kit-Quiz[6505:907] (null)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Can anyone advice either a new way of shuffling this array, or advice me on how to avoid this error..!? I'm building for iOS 5 and I'm using Xcode45-DP1. Thanks in advance!

**(EDIT)**

I've also tried this method and I get the same error:

```
NSMutableArray *shuffledArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *standardArray = [self.chosenTeamDict objectForKey:@"clubs"];

    for(int s = 0; s < [standardArray count]; s++){
        int random = arc4random() % s;
        [shuffledArray addObject:[standardArray objectAtIndex:random]];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", shuffledArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *standardArray = [self.chosenTeamDict objectForKey:@"clubs"];

int length = 10; // int length = [yourArray count];
NSMutableArray *indexes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:length];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) [indexes addObject:[shuffledArray objectAtIndex:i]];
NSMutableArray *shuffle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:length];
while ([indexes count])
{
    int index = rand()%[indexes count];
    [shuffle addObject:[indexes objectAtIndex:index]];
    [indexes removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
for (int i=0; i<[shuffle count]; i++) NSLog(@"%@", [shuffle objectAtIndex:i]);

NSLog(@"%@", shuffle);
```

^^ ANSWER

Comment: It is select random but repeat the questions

Answer (score 1):

Try Fisher-Yates shuffle. It goes like this:

```
int count = shuffledArray.count;

for(int i=count; i>0; i--) {

 int j = arc4random_uniform(count);

 [shuffledArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:j withObjectAtIndex:i];

}
```

make sure that your array is non-nil and all the entries are allocated objects :)

Source: [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: Dont you mean `for(int i=count; i>0; i--) {`?

Comment: apparently not: "Implicit declaration of function 'arc4_uniform' is invalid in C99"

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu still the same error as before. I've found the best method below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11402267/1223400

Comment: I think your error is not about the algorithm but the arc4 function, a library that contains it might be missing. Also about your solution, beware that rand() is not a good pseudo-random number generator, most likely you will get the same results over and over again if you're starting out with the same order of the elements in the array

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu this solution works perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11402267/1223400

Answer (score 0):

First, you really should enable exception breakpoints. In XCode on the left-hand panel, click the breakpoint tab, click the "+" sign at the bottom-left -> exception breakpoint -> done.

<s>I suspect your problem lies here:</s>

```
int random = arc4random() % [shuffleTwo count];
```

If [shuffleTwo count] evaluates to zero (also if shuffleTwo is nil) it will throw a division by zero exception. Edit: Doesn't seem to be the case in Objective-C.